# SimpleOpenNI not working on Processing 3.1.1 using Mac OS 10.11.5 El Capitan

Tags: macos, processing, openni, simple-openni, nite

I keep getting this error when I run a example code from SimpleOpenNI such as **NoSuchMethodError: You may be using a library that's incompatible with this version of Processing**.

I have tried in vain everywhere to find and properly install an OpenNI version that is compatible with OS 10.11.5 AND can be used by Processing! I have OpenNi SDK (v1.5.7.10) + NITE(NITE-Bin-Dev-MacOSX-v1.5.2.21) + SensorKinect-unstablev5.1.2.1. + libtool + libusb but as read here: https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Supported-Platforms and here: https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes a lot of things have changed with Processing 3.1.1.

Does anyone know of a previous version(s) (processing, OpenNI, NITE, etc) that will work with my MacOS, a link to a tutorial, or have had the same problem but fixed it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would try is downgrading your Processing to version 2.2.1. You can get it [here](https://processing.org/download/?processing).

Comment: Cool ok. I did it, it works but now when I run I get this error: "Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM." [1] "Please install the desired version." Any ideas? Searched all over for forcing Mac to run JDK 1.6.0

Comment: @EricReyna I would start out by googling that error. If you still can't figure it out, feel free to ask a new question with your updated information.

Comment: **This worked by installing 2.2.1!** I had installed 1.5.1 and now I installed 2.2.1 and it works. Thanks!